# How do I use a Dutch COVID test to travel to the UK in summer 2021?

Tags: uk, covid-19, netherlands

I'm in the Netherlands and trying to travel to the UK. According to the UK government "The Dutch Government are providing free tests for travel. If you choose to use these tests, you should check that the type of test and the test result certificate meets the full testing requirements (e.g. name of the test provider and their contact details, if appropriate)"
https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/netherlands/coronavirus

The Dutch government confirm that in July and August 2021 I can use the free corona test to travel to countries outside of Europe (meaning the EU, I assume):
https://www.rijksoverheid.nl/onderwerpen/coronavirus-covid-19/reizen-en-vakantie/coronabewijs/gratis-coronatest

I've had my test, got a negative result, and downloaded the certificate. Now I'm trying to work out if this meets all the UK requirements. Both the UK and Dutch government websites aren't really very helpful on this.

[The UK's requirements](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/coronavirus-covid-19-testing-for-people-travelling-to-england) include:

- "the name of the test provider and their contact details", the certificate says that the testing centre is a "facility approved by the state of The Netherlands" and that the certificate issuer is the "Ministry of Health, Welfare and Sport"
- "confirmation of the device used for the test, or that the test was a PCR test", the certificate says that the test manufacturer was Abbot Rapid Diagnostics and the type of test is "Sneltest (RAT)". (The online certificate also says that it was a Panbio COVID-19 Ag Rapid Test, which meets the UK's requirements for entry, though this isn't shown on the PDF. It also provides a bit more information about the test provider.)

So does anyone know whether this is sufficient?

(Supplementary question: do I need to print the certificate out, or is a PDF on my phone / laptop enough?)

Actual experience from anyone who's done this since the current rules came in at the start of July would be very helpful.

Comment: The UK gov page you link to is for travel advice *from* the UK to the Netherlands, AFAIK. Have you checked the advice in https://www.gov.uk/guidance/coronavirus-covid-19-testing-for-people-travelling-to-england?

Comment: @Traveller yes I have - it was where I got the information in the post about the UK's requirements - but thanks for the suggestion. I edited the post to make this clearer. The challenge is to work out whether what's on the certificate counts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it turns out that the free test was fine.

I downloaded the test certificate as a PDF via [CoronaCheck Print Portaal](https://coronacheck.nl/en/print/) and showed it to the check in agent on my phone as well as my [Passenger Locator Form](https://www.gov.uk/provide-journey-contact-details-before-travel-uk), this seemed to be what they expected.